# iterating through the chars on the reference of a string

Tags: rust

This does not work:

```
let mut word = String::from("kobin");
for x in &word.chars() {
    println!("looping through word: {}", x);
}
```

But this works:

```
let mut word = String::from("kobin");
let word_ref = &word;
for x in word_ref.chars() {
    println!("looping through word: {}", x);
}
```

whats the difference. Aren't both referencing to the `word`?

Comment: Operator precedence – but doesn’t just `word.chars()` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&word.chars()` is the same as `&(word.chars())`, so you're taking the iterator and borrowing it. Rust points out in this case that a reference to [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) (the iterator type) is not an iterator, but a `Chars` itself is. Parenthesizing fully will work

```
for x in (&word).chars() { ... }
```

But when calling methods on things, Rust is smart and will automatically borrow, so you can simply do

```
for x in word.chars() { ... }
```

and Rust is smart enough to know that `str::chars` only needs `&self` and will insert the `&` for you.